# Showing that $\frac{A}{1+x} + \frac{B}{1+y}$ is approximately $\frac{A + B}{1 + \frac{A}{A+B}x + \frac{B}{A+B}y }$ for small $x, y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For work I have been doing a lot of calculations which look sort of like summing terms similar to $\frac{A}{1+x}$ and $\frac{B}{1+y}$ for some $A, B$ and small values of $0 \leq x, y \leq 0.1$. In my experience I have found that this is approximately equal to $\frac{A + B}{1 + \frac{A}{A+B}x + \frac{B}{A+B}y }$. The best thing about this approximate equality is that the numerator is simply a linear combination of the earlier two numerators. Of course, it also holds exactly true if A or B is zero!

It would help me a great deal both if I can somehow show that my hypothesis is true. Of course I know equality does not hold, but if I can convince my colleagues that atleast this is approximately true, we can simplify our calculations and calculation speed dramatically!

Does anyone have any idea if this indeed can be shown to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try Taylor/Maclaurin series:
$$
\frac{A}{1+x} = A( 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 \cdots)
$$
for $|x| < 1$. Use the start of that series to start your approximations.

Comment: Hey great hint! This is exactly the tip I needed. By applying the Maclaurin series to the two sums, and then applying the same relationship in reverse I got exactly what I needed. It also helps me show that the error is only of order O(x^2) and O(y^2)! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the method suggested by @Karn worked for me. That is, use the Maclaurin series
$$
\frac{A}{1+x} = A( 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 \cdots)
$$
for $|x| < 1$. Apply this to both elements of the sum and discard all values of order $x^2$ and $y^2$ or higher. Then you can multiply the $x$ and $y$ terms by $\frac{A+B}{A+B}$ and collect all terms of $(A+B)$. Then apply the Maclaurin series in reverse to obtain the final result!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look at $\;\displaystyle \frac{a}{u}  +\frac{b}{v} - \frac{(a+b)^2}{a u + b v } = \frac{ab(u-v)^2}{uv(a u + b v)}\,$ for $u=x+1, v=y+1$. The RHS gives the error of the proposed approximation.